# How to unlock Kicks shoe shop in Animal Crossing New Leaf

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

How are you supposed to unlock Kicks shoe shop in *Animal Crossing New Leaf*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [AC:NL wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Kicks_%28Store%29):

> It is built next door to the Able Sisters tailor shop when the player has spent 8,000 Bells in Able Sisters. 10 days must also have passed since the creation of the Town. It takes three days for Kicks to be built.

So spend lots of money at the Able Sisters, and the shop will be built once you've spent the required cash, and ten days have passed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to spend 8000 bells at the Able Sisters. Also, ten days have to pass since you created and moved into the town. But it takes a longer time to build unlike other buildings. It takes three days.
 If you want to find out more, go to www.thonky.com.